# how much CSS sprite reduce page loading time?

Tags: css, image, sprite, css-sprites, performance-testing

I know you can reduce page load time by using CSS sprite. As this will reduce round trip, etc.

Is their any numerical value or performance test that by using CSS sprite how much average page loading time you can save. I know this will depend on the site. I am interested to know about a general data for e commerce site like Amazon.com

Besides, if you use async image loading like [JAIL](https://github.com/sebarmeli/JAIL) how much time you could save. I know u can't load everything asynchronously.

Comment: It will depend on the number of images being put into a sprite and how fast your server handles ruquests.

Comment: Definitely, But i was wondering is there any general experiment to estimate benefit.

Comment: Simple: time your page loading speed with and without sprites. That's the best way to tell. Google's pagespeed is a useful tool as well.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. However, that would be one single case which will not be a generally acceptable number. If i dont get any number, i will do it.

Comment: Google chrome comes with webinspector which can tell you what time it took to load each component on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Having a large sprite, versus a small image, the large sprite isn't that much bigger in file size than the small image, assuming you line your images in the sprite horizontally like your supposed to.

Most browsers will do about 6 simultaneous downloads at once. So a general rule of thumb is, if you have more than 6 icons, or theme graphics, it should be sprited. If you have photos or illustrations, they should not be sprited.

Comment: To expand on this, semantically it makes sense for photos and such to be `<img>` images, whereas icons are naturally more part of the CSS styling (as sprites)

Answer (score 1):

Improper usage of sprites will lead to overload server. Sprites are used to reduce the number of server requests, but large srpites of jpg format can be bad.

It is like balance either all smaller images of less size or a sprite that i of smaller size that covers more images

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/03/26/css-sprites-useful-technique-or-potential-nuisance/

> The page loading can reduce upto 10X factor when they are use
>   optimally!!

Hope this helps